# How can I configure HTTPClient to authenticate against a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: java, http, proxy, apache-commons-httpclient

I need to set up proxy authentication against a SOCKS proxy.
I found out [this post](http://cephas.net/blog/2007/11/14/java-commons-http-client-and-http-proxies/) giving instructions that appear to work with common HTTP proxies.

```
        httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("proxyserver.example.com", 8080);

        HttpState state = new HttpState();
        state.setProxyCredentials(new AuthScope("proxyserver.example.com", 8080), 
           new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        httpclient.setState(state);
```

Would that work with *SOCKS* proxies as well or do I have to do something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Features page](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html) of Apache HTTPClient says:

> Transparent connections through SOCKS proxies (version 4 & 5) using native Java socket support.

With "transparent", I guess they mean that it works without you needing to do anything special. Do you have a SOCKS proxy available somewhere? Can't you just try it out to see if it works?

Comment: I can't install a SOCKS proxy at my workplace, but I'll be testing that soon at a customer site.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Java supports Socks proxy configuration via preferences:

- `socksProxyHost` for the host name of the SOCKS proxy server
- `socksProxyPort` for the port number, the default value being `1080`

e.g.

```
java -DsocksProxyHost=socks.mydomain.com
```

(**edit**) For your example, if the socks proxy was configured in the way outlined before:

```
httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("proxyserver.example.com", 8080);
Credentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","password");
httpclient.getState().setProxyCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, cred);
```

You can also use this variant (without httpclient):

```
SocketAddress addr = new
InetSocketAddress("webcache.mydomain.com", 8080);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr); // Type.HTTP for HTTP
```

So completing the previous example, we can now add:

```
URL url = new URL("http://java.sun.com/");
URConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
```

HTH

Comment: is that a org.apache.http.client.HttpClient? i dont see those methods on httpClient 4.5.2! i mean getConfiguration() and getState()

Comment: yea, they don't exist anymore. The original answer is now 13 years old.

Answer (score 4):

SOCKS is not supported by HttpClient 3 natively. You can try the SOCKS support in JDK as suggested by others. The side effect is that your whole JVM will go through the same SOCKS proxy.

Java 5 supports Username/Password authentication in SOCKS (type 2). All you have to do is to setup the authenticator like this,

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Again, this may not work for you because it affects all authentication in your JVM (HTTP auth, Proxy Auth).

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a custom socket factory which implements the SOCKS protocol, and register it as your default HTTP protocol handler. This solution has a limitation similar to tuergeist's answer above has - it applies globally, to any HTTP connection you'll establish through HttpClient.

If you find this a problem, take a look at [this correspondence](http://old.nabble.com/Best-practise-to-add-SOCKS-proxy-support--td25107866.html), where Oleg suggests using HttpClient 4.0, but also refers to a possible patch in HostConfiguration class for HttpClient 3.x.

Another possible solution, which is my personal favorite, is to write a wrapper HTTP proxy to the socks proxy.

Comment: The link seems dead

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "socks.xyz.com");
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "1000");
```

and it's working fine.

Comment: If you do that in Tomcat it sets the property for the whole Tomcat JVM. Other apps might not want that.