# Java Proxy client class that supports authentication

Tags: java, proxy, socks

I'm looking for a java socks Proxy client class that supports authetication, any suggestions?  The java.net.Proxy does not support authentication.

Edit:
I can't seem to find a way that would attach authentication data to particular proxy host via socket.  Authenticator.setDefault() allows only one set of credential.

```
 Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
  protected  PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication(){
   PasswordAuthentication p=new PasswordAuthentication("xxx", "xxx".toCharArray());
   return p;
  }
 });
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx", xxx));

   Socket sock = new Socket(proxy);

   sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(server,xx));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java supports Socks proxy configuration via a registered `java.net.Authenticator` or via preferences as documented in the [Networking Properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html):

> **SOCKS protocol support settings**
>
> The SOCKS username and password are
> acquired in the following way. First,
> if the application has registered a
> `java.net.Authenticator` default
> instance, then this will be queried
> with the protocol set to the string
> "SOCKS5", and the prompt set to to the
> string "SOCKS authentication". If the
> authenticator does not return a
> username/password or if no
> authenticator is registered then the
> system checks for the user preferences
> "`java.net.socks.username`" and
> "`java.net.socks.password`". If these
> preferences do not exist, then the
> system property "`user.name`" is checked
> for a username. In this case, no
> password is supplied.
>
> **socksProxyHost**
> **socksProxyPort** (default: 1080)
> Indicates the name of the SOCKS proxy server and the port number that will be used by the SOCKS protocol layer. If socksProxyHost is specified then all TCP sockets will use the SOCKS  proxy server to establish a connection or accept one. The SOCKS proxy server can either be a SOCKS v4 or v5 server and it has to allow for unauthenticated connections.

For client code examples, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388822/how-can-i-configure-httpclient-to-authenticate-against-a-socks-proxy/1388903#1388903) on Stack Overflow.

**EDIT: Update of the answer as per comment**

The side effect of the SOCKS support in JDK is that your whole JVM will go through the same SOCKS proxy. So this may not work for you.

The `Authenticator` affects all authentication in your JVM (HTTP auth, Proxy Auth). So again, this may not work for you.

In your case, a possible solution would be to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) (the successor of the legacy [Commons HTTP Client 3.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html)). Check out the [samples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) and especially the [Request via a proxy](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientExecuteProxy.java) and [Proxy authentication](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientProxyAuthentication.java) examples.

Comment: what if I need to change authentication login&password based on the different proxy hosts?, Authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication() only allows one set of credential.

Comment: I think Authenticator is fine for me since I can use Authenticator.getRequestHost() to assign different Authenticator for each host.  I need a Socket, not an http based client, so HttpClient does not work for me.

Comment: Note that the links in the above answer are now dead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this HttpClient (Not Apache's),

http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/

This is simply an URL handler so you can use the usual HTTPUrlConnection. It supports SOCKS and other proxy.