# Apache HTTP Client socks proxy

Tags: java, apache, http, client, socks

I am currently working at a web requests project and I am using Apache Http Client library. I try to connect to a server (E.g. http://www.google.com) with an working Socks v4/5 tested with mozilla firefox but the problem is that I never get a response. Only different errors...

Here is a code snippet:

```
//HttpClient
DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
//A class defined by me
Proxy proxy = bla bla;
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(proxy.getIP(), proxy.getPort());
if (proxy.getUsername() != null) {
   http.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                            new AuthScope(proxy.getIP(), proxy.getPort()),
                            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxy.getUsername(), proxy.getPassword()));
}
http.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, host);
```

Can anyone tell a proper way to initiate comunnication through SOCKS proxies? Thanks!

Note: The code above works perfect with HTTP proxies.

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed or server unreacheable, etc. BUT if I use the proxy with mozilla it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Http proxy and socks proxy has very different protocols ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Comparison ).
For your question:
You can do thTis by native java socket ( [How can I configure HTTPClient to authenticate against a SOCKS proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388822/how-can-i-configure-httpclient-to-authenticate-against-a-socks-proxy) ) or create your own implementation over DefaultClientConnectionOperator, here is good guide ( http://4devops.blogspot.com/2011/10/httphttps-over-socks-proxy-with-java.html )